# Updating to PHP 5.4 breaks Drupal 7.25 with Strict warning: Declaration on bootstrap.inc

Tags: 7

I tried updating to PHP 5.4, but got a few errors. These aren't critical errors right? seems like its only warnings.

I'm using Drupal 7.20 What do the following errors mean exactly? And how can they be resolved? Can I just upgrade my Drupal 7 to the latest 7.31 as of 2014-09-24 to fix these issues?

```
Strict warning: Declaration of Messaging_User_Destination::validate_address() should be compatible with Messaging_Destination::validate_address($address, $type = NULL) in _registry_check_code() (line 3080 of /home/xxx/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Strict warning: Declaration of Messaging_User_Destination::format_address() should be compatible with Messaging_Destination::format_address($address, $format = MESSAGING_FORMAT_PLAIN, $type = NULL) in _registry_check_code() (line 3080 of /home/xxx/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc).

Strict warning: Declaration of Messaging_Mail_Address::validate_address() should be compatible with Messaging_Destination::validate_address($address, $type = NULL) in require_once() (line 208 of /home/xxx/public_html/sites/all/modules/messaging/messaging_mail/messaging_mail.inc).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These aren't critical errors right?

No, it's just a warning. Not fatal. It comes from the [`E_STRICT` error constant](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), which as of PHP5.4 was included in `E_ALL`. It's quite common to see those errors after upgrading 5.3 to 5.4 (not just for Drupal), as most people copy the bulk of their config from the previous version.

The constant itself provides this to error reporting:

> Enable to have PHP suggest changes to your code which will ensure the best interoperability and forward compatibility of your code.

---

> What do the following errors mean exactly?

In Drupal terms, it means one or more contrib modules you have installed contain code that targets older version of PHP (or at least hasn't been updated recently). Specifically, PHP is complaining that the arguments or access modification of a method on a child class doesn't match the same method on the parent class.

> Can I just upgrade my Drupal 7 to the latest 7.31 as of 2014-09-24 to fix these issues?

In your case the warning is being caused by the messaging_mail module, so updating core won't do anything (though you should update ASAP, you're a long way behind). You could [disable strict errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983286/disabling-strict-standards-in-php-5-4) if you just want to hide the warning, but the best way forward is to report this as a bug to the appropriate module.

Comment: what are some other commonly known compatibility issues like this that would arise from upgrading to php 5.4?

Comment: The full list is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php), the most common one I've seen apart from the strict warning is that Call-time pass by reference was removed.  Some older libraries make heavy use of that. But it's quite rare in the Drupal world in my experience, you just happen to be using a module which needs a bit of attention. I've got loads of sites running on php5.5 without any problems for what it's worth

Comment: so you just ignore the disable strict errors by suppressing them? so would it be safe to say if im going to upgrade to 5.4 i might aswell go for 5.5? thanks clive!

Comment: Yeah you can suppress them (best not to obviously but life isn't always that clear cut), the warning is basically that at some point in the future doing that will probably raise a fatal error. You should be fine with 5.5, the [backwards incompatibilities](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.incompatible.php) are unlikely to affect you I'd say